# Make Bootstrap dropdown menu full width of device and stop icon from moving

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with three columns at the top in a fluid-container, followed by the rest of the website in a container below.

In the fluid container I have three sections at the top. The middle one redirects to the homepage, while I want to create a dropdown menu for the left and right ones. I've used a link-style button with a background picture to do this, however, when I press the dropdown button, the button itself jumps up slightly:
[image: Dropdown closed and bell icon is in line with home icon][image: dropdown open and bell icon has moved up to the top of the page]

There is also the issue of the dropdown menu itself extending only as far as the left side dropdown div. Is there a way to make it expand across the width of the device?

The code:

```css
#header {
    background-image: url(http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/header.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100vw;
    height:30.45vw;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
    position:relative; 
    z-index:0;
} 

.topbar {
    background-image: url(http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/topbar.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 10.7189vw;
    max-height: 50vh;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.topbar div {
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    align-self: center;
}

.topbar div img {
    height: 25%;
    width: 24%;
    max-height: 8.2vmax;
    max-width: 8.2vmax;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropup,
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #232323;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
          box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #262626;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn-link {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #337ab7;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header id="header">
<div class="topbar">
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/notificationsnew.png" style="float:left"></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Notification 1</li>
        <li>Notification 2</li>
        <li>Notification 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div><div><a href="http://m.elysiumrpg.com/index.php"><img src="http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/home.png"></a></div><div><img src="http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/hamburger.png" style="float:right"></div>
</div>
</header>
```

If it helps at all, the page is live [here](http://m.elysiumrpg.com/index.php), and my problem can be seen by clicking on the right hand side hamburger menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc( 100vw - 5px );
    margin : auto ;
}
```

> Add this style to avoid jumping of the menu button...
>   I have written this code by referring your **live** website ( http://m.elysiumrpg.com/index.php ).

`100vw` means 100% of viewport width.

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly for the width, but in order for both menus to work as I want, I had to take out some of the general css and put them inline css for that dropdown specifically.. and now the menu is jumping up again. Is it the above combination that fixes this?

Answer (score 0):

---

For the menu full width try this snippet. Check out [there for more](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns).

> JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function(event){
        $('.dropdown-menu').css("width", $('.container').width()+'px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown buttons are located inside blocks with the `margin: auto;` property. While the dropdown is collapsed, block's top margin equals `11.359px`. When the dropdown opens the top margin becomes zero.

Try to fix the `margin-top` property. For example:

```
.topbar div {
  margin-top: 11px;
}
```